# Remove spacing and decimals from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, trim

To start with it has to be compatible with all modern browsers (since it is used on mobile devices). What do I want to do?

Well I have one meta tag that I have to check, because people write it differently into their DOM.

So my example is below. I need to remove spacing and decimals if they are existing.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

So I get the content of that meta:

```
var getViewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
var check = getViewport.getAttribute('content');
    console.log(check); // output: width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no
```

I am not even able to trim it. I tried some trimming functions such as:

```
el.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

But it does not do anything in this particular case.

I need to compare if that content matches, else I will replace it with proper content.
People write it on many ways, so I don't want to compare each possible way, but instead make it all look the same, so if exists then it would be same match as my example above.

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no
width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no
width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no
width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no
```

And they can also add some spacing and remove others on some places by purpose or accidentaly... If you understand what I am trying to say. This would probably need some editing due to fast typing and grammar issues.

Bottom line, can anyone teach me how to trim, remove decimals from the `"var check"` so any case if it exists would match this type of string: `width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no`

Comment: Is the string elements always in the same order?

Comment: Also very good point. Not sure if this "viewport" has to be in this particular order. I took it of off Bootstrap.

Comment: Well, my solution will be a bit more complex... using a map with the pair key/value... I'll do a jsfiddle to explain it ;)

Comment: Alright @PatrickFerreira. I will wait for that solution as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another, more comprehensive approach you could do, if you want to allow for "any order" of the arguments.

Remove ".0", split on the commas, trim the spaces, sort the list, and re-join.

For example:

```
check = check.replace(/\.0*\b/g, "").split(/\s*,\s*/g).sort().join(",");
```

This would allow the following to match:

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no
user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width
```

See it in action? [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jepuwemuwedu/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Now you thought of every possibility. So the order does not really matter for this meta tag to be valid ? Then this will do very good job!

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a regular expression to remove all spaces, and all ".0".  This will do it:

```
check = check.replace(/(\s+|\.0*\b)/g, "")
```

Comment: This is a good one to go with. My solution basically does the same but with much more explanational stuff. For programming and efficiency you should go with this one from Scott.

Comment: Tested right after @androidavid answer. Also works and it's quite short :D ! Thank you for the answer +1

Answer (score 1):

First you normalize it:

```
var your_string = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no';
var your_comparison_string = your_string.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

After that you could search for any floating numbers. In this case it is sufficient to search for those WITH dot because you will norm to those without:

```
var search = your_comparison_string.match(/\d\.\d/g);
for (var i in search) {
  your_comparison_string = your_comparison_string.replace(search[i], parseInt(search[i]));
}
```

Comment: Woooh this is longer than I though! However it works fine. Thanks for explanations as well +1